# How to identify which view is clicked programmatically

Tags: react-native

I am developing an android application on react native. Which has several buttons and I want to perform different actions on click of each button.

I am quite familiar with android sdk, in android sdk `android:id` attribute is present to identify components. But the problem in react native is how to identify which button is clicked by user.

```
<View style = { styles.button_container } >
      <Text 
           onPress={() =>  } >Component
      </Text>
      <Text 
           onPress={() => } >About
      </Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can send a parameter with the button clicked, something like this:

```
function MenuComponent(props) {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.button_container } >
      <Text 
       onPress={() =>  props.onClick('component')} >Component
      </Text>
      <Text 
       onPress={() => props.onClick('about')} >About
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Assuming you are sending an `onClick` prop from the parent. The the parent will know which of the children elements was clicked.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  onClickMenu = (button) => {
    console.log(button);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MenuComponent onClick={this.onClickMenu} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The `onClickMenu` will get the `button` param with the clicked button on the child component, from there you can decide what to do for each case.